# Making array from sentence

Tags: php

I've got this sentence from database

```
0| Future plan 1| Low 2| Normal 3| High 4| Highest
```

And I've need to make it look similar to:

```
[0] => Future plan
[1] => Low
[2] => Normal
[3] => High
[4] => Highest
```

I cant find any thread, similar to this. Help please.

Comment: Is it a single string or?

Comment: @Epodax single string. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found something that SHOULD do the trick for you: [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

```
$string = "0| Future plan 1| Low 2| Normal 3| High 4| Highest";
$array = preg_split("/[0-9]+\|/", $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Answer (score 2):

@ankhzet pointed out a flaw which this answer covers.

```
<?php
$v              = '0| Future plan 22 2| Normal 123| Low 3| High 4| Highest';
$arraySplit     = preg_split("/([0-9]+)\|/", $v, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
$arrayResult    = array();
for($i = 1; $i < count($arraySplit); $i+=2){
    $arrayResult[$arraySplit[$i]] = $arraySplit[$i+1];
}
pre($arrayResult);
?>
```

New output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Future plan 22
    [2] => Normal
    [123] => Low
    [3] => High
    [4] => Highest
)
```

**OLD**

This method will maintain the ID's and is shorter than @ankhzet's answer.
Here if you need it:

```
preg_match_all("/(\d+)\|([^0-9]+)/", $v, $array);
$array = array_combine($array[1], $array[2]);
pre($array);
```

Output looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  Future plan 
    [2] =>  Normal 
    [1] =>  Low 
    [3] =>  High 
    [4] =>  Highest
)
```

FYI, `pre()` is just a function the wraps `print_r()` inside `<pre></pre>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

First change database sentence and then in your case use php function `explode ("| " , $string)`. This function can explode the string to array by delimiter.

Comment: A simple explode won't work since the integers are before the | so you'll end up with a strange looking array

Comment: Like that `Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => Future plan 1 [2] => Low 2 [3] => Normal 3 [4] => High 4 [5] => Highest ) ` in [0] should be Future plan

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<?php
   $str = "Future plan | Low | Normal | High | Highest";
   print_r (explode("|",$str));
?>
```

Comment: A simple explode won't work since the integers are before the | so you'll end up with a strange looking array

Answer (score 1):

Use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
$words = preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '', $string);//remove all numbers from string
$array = explode ("|" , $words);
$array2 = array_filter($array)//remove empty elements
```

Comment: Like that `Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => Future plan 1 [2] => Low 2 [3] => Normal 3 [4] => High 4 [5] => Highest ) ` in [0] should be Future plan

Comment: Now it looks liek this `Array ( [0] => [1] => Future plan [2] => Low [3] => Normal [4] => High [5] => Highest ) `

Answer (score 1):

Given that in your string you have `|`, I made the following (extra checks must be made):

```
$string = '0| Future plan 1| Low 2| Normal 3| High 4| Highest';
$string = str_replace('|','',$string); //replace |
$length = strlen($string); //get length
for($i=0; $i<=$length-1;$i++)
{
    if(is_numeric($string[$i])) { //get numbers
        $word[$string[$i]] ='';
        $lastIndex = $string[$i]; //save last found
    } else {
        if($string[$i]!=' ') { //if not space append to array element of last number found
            $word[$lastIndex] .= $string[$i];
        }
    }
}
var_dump($word);

array (size=5)
  0 => string 'Futureplan' (length=10)
  1 => string 'Low' (length=3)
  2 => string 'Normal' (length=6)
  3 => string 'High' (length=4)
  4 => string 'Highest' (length=7)
```

Answer (score 1):

REGEXP, suggested by @Epodax  won't keep indexes:

```
$v = '0| Future plan 2| Normal 1| Low 3| High 4| Highest';
$array = preg_split("/[0-9]+\|/", $v, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

dump($array);
// array:5 [▼
//   0 => " Future plan "
//   1 => " Normal "
//   2 => " Low "
//   3 => " High "
//   4 => " Highest"
// ]
```

If that matters, probably better be to use this:

```
$v = '0| Future plan 2| Normal 1| Low 3| High 4| Highest';
$v .= '0|';
$r = [];
while ($v) {
  if (!preg_match('/(\d+)\|(.+?)(?:(\d+)\|)/', $v, $m, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE))
    break;

  $idx = intval($m[1][0]);
  $r[$idx] = trim($m[2][0]);

  if (($offset = $m[3][1]) >= strlen($v))
    break;

  $v = substr($v, $offset);
}

dump($r);
// array:5 [▼
//   0 => "Future plan"
//   2 => "Normal"
//   1 => "Low"
//   3 => "High"
//   4 => "Highest"
// ]
```

Comment: ... but don't break, if there are numbers in between... "0| Future plan 2| Normal 1| Between 200 and 300 3| High 4| Highest". Also, filters output for whitespace.